# Robust common mean inference

Tags: regression, anova, t-test, outliers, robust

In an ANOVA-like setting I have several groups of variables that I expect to have the same mean, $\mu$. Quite often some of the groups would have shifted means, $\mu + \Delta$, due to effects beyond my control ($\Delta$ is random).

One goal is estimating $\mu$. However, I would also like to identify these "outlier" groups and study them (they are not really outliers, in the sense that they are not just junk.)

My current approach is to identify such outlier groups via pairwise t-tests.

**Update**

**Current approach**
The approach that I have currently adopted consists of pairwise t-tests complemented by TOST equivalence tests. I then construct a graph, where each group serves as a node and the connected nodes are the pairs of groups that, according to the tests, have close means. And then I choose the biggest connected cluster in this graph, as the one representing the true mean (this is algorithmically easy to do.)

I would like to streamline this procedure, so I am looking for a better method to identify the outlier groups or to determine the mean without excluding them.

**Possible alternative approaches**

*Lasso regression*
One alternative seems to be using a version of lasso regression, which would push the deviations from means to zero, unless the data dictate otherwise. This would probably produce a directly a cluster of groups with the true mean, but I haven't tried this yet.

*Bayesian model testing*
Another alternative is to use Bayesian model testing, calculating probabilities of all possible combinations of groups where some of them have a common mean and others do not. However this approach seems computationally intensive (if not prohibitive) for 20+ groups.

*Robust regression*
Robust regression with Huber or Tukey loss functions seems an efficient approach

*Expectation maximization*
I haven't tried this yet. Its main drawback is that it requires specifying a model for outlying observations. 
Comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just a long-tailed distribution for the data, so outliers would not be a problem any more?

Comment: It could work to determine the common mean, which, I suppose, is how my question was formulated. However, I would like to identify these groups and study them as well.

Comment: This depends on what you think an "outlier" is. Are you after finding all groups for which $\Delta$ is clearly nonzero (i.e., significantly different from zero, which implies that the more observations you have in that group, the smaller a difference can count as "outlier")? Or does an "outlier" have to be truly outlying in some sense, i.e., far away from the main bulk of the means, which requires a specification of how "far" - for which there may be a subject matter background? In any case you need to make decisions yourself - the parameter in Lasso, the prior, the significance level...

Comment: When using TOST I do set a parameter defining the allowed variation around the mean. The "outliers" are different "in some sense" - probably coming from a mixture of the main distribution with something else.

Comment: What you're doing doesn't look totally off, but running a (large?) number of pairwise tests doesn't seem optimal to me. Particularly because A can be similar enough to B, and B to C, and A and C still can be very different but would be "connected" in your graph if I get things right. (To be continued.)

Comment: I think I would write down a model where there's a overall mean $\mu$ and group means $\mu+\Delta_i$ with $\Delta_i=0$ for the majority of groups or so. The test problem would be $|\Delta_i|<\delta$ against $|\Delta_i|>\delta$ (given threshold) for every group. The thing is I don't know whether something like this exists in the literature. If we were collaborating I could probably look around and work something out if nothing can be found. It doesn't seem that difficult, but too difficult to solve in a CrossValidated posting. Maybe ask you local Stats department.

Comment: What you say makes a lot of sense. One concern is that overall mean $\mu$ is also affected by outliers, so the result may be dependent on the order in which I exclude them. Or, if I keep all of them, some may test incorrectly.

The actual problem is somewhat more complicated - $\mu$ is different from one measurement to another, but is is the same for all groups. Doing pairwise comparisons allows to exclude $\mu$, testing the difference of two groups against zero mean.

Comment: Do you know something about the $\Delta_i$? All positive? All similar (when not zero)? Any idea about a prior probability they are zero?